# How to copy ODBC Composite data sources from one server to another?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, odbc

Both servers are Windows 2008 R2 x64.  I have tried exporting [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI] but it doesn't contain the actual data source configuration for a Composite 6.1 data source.  I would like to export the whole configuration (with username/password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Sysmtem DNS then Username and password are not stored in the ODBC registry.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.data.odbc/NW6ACwEm9Dw